# Azure B2C sign in with username?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm pretty new working with B2C custom policies, and currently I'm trying to setup an integration with one client using SAML. That client is sending us their employeeId as ID in the SAML payloads.
I got an integration working with okta with I'm using emails, but haven't had any luck with something different.

This is how my technical profile looks like when I have it working with an email account.

```xml
<TechnicalProfiles>
  <TechnicalProfile Id="MySAML2">
    <DisplayName>SAML Integration</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="email" />
      ...
    </OutputClaims>
  </TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>
```

So I've tried changing it to look like this

```xml
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="objectId" />
```

or

```xml
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
```

or

```xml
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="name" />
```

or

```xml
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="key" />
```

but none of those have worked so far. Any advice will be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a write-up of the mappings [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/mapping-user-claims-from-an-external-idp-to-azure-ad-b2c-34ec19528dbe).

The RHS in the Technical Profile is the SAML name. The LHS is the B2C name.

So if SAML is sending a claim called "employeeId" than the mapping is:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="employeeId" />
```

But you need to look at the SAML attributes to see if there is a claim called "employeeId".